# "Undeclared requirements" error when running problem file with planner

Tags: error-handling, pddl

I keep getting an "undeclared requirement :typing" error when I run my problem file with a planner, even though I've already declared it in my domain file

The requirements in my domain file:

```
    (:requirements :typing :types :durative-actions :fluents :numeric-fluents)
    (:types patient surgeon rooms speciality injury)
```

In my  problem file:

```
    (define (problem surgery)
    (:domain emergency_room)
    (:objects 
         patient1 patient2 patient3 - patient
         surgeon1 surgeon2 surgeon3 - surgeon
         trauma dental cardio - speciality
         heart tooth accident - injury)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which planner do you use?

```
:typing
```

means that the domain uses types that you define below. But to the best of my knowledge, the

```
:types
```

requirement does not exist and should only be used as a keyword for the actual types. Therefore, you probably need to remove :types from the requirement section.

Also note that most planners are quite robust against missing requirements tags. So sometimes it's a good idea to omit some of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of requirements supported by PDDL 1.2

https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/requirements#typing

Indeed, `:typing` is the planner requirement, `:types` is the keyword for declaring *object types* inside the PDDL *domain*.

For requirements specified by later PDDL versions, search this page for *List of PDDL x.y Requirements*.

https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/requirements